# Draggable floating panel in React without libraries

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I would like to create a Draggable floating panel in Peace without libraries using mouse events, touch events, or pointer events, but I don't quite understand how to implement this

Here is an example of a similar panel
https://mobile.ant.design/components/floating-panel

I tried using pointer events, but without disabling default actions in the mobile browser (for example, updating the screen), pointer events did not work correctly, they just did not work at some points, and if you disable default actions, pointer events did not work at all in the mobile browser

Comment: Please add the code effort you have been applying for the requirement, so the reader will find it easy to understand what type of drag you should try. For example, react-dnd, react-draggable etc.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.